# How do I use the 'to' and 'from' property for a bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, events, carousel

On the documentation page for bootstrap's carousel there is a property for on under the events tab but I don't know the syntax to use it and can't find any examples.

From bootstrap's carousel documentation:

Bootstrap’s carousel class exposes two events for hooking into carousel functionality. Both events have the following additional properties:

from: The index of the current item
to: The index of the next item

Comment: They are just event properties.  `$(selector).on('somecaroselevent', function (e) { e.to; e.from; });`

Comment: These are properties on the events that are emitted from the carousel.  They are a thing you _receive_ not a thing you set.  As they are indices, I would expect them to be returned as numbers.